# How to update all columns consecutively when updating a column from a table?

Tags: kdb

I currently have a table `t` with three columns of interest that I am trying to work with. The data looks as below:

| on | off | csum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1b | 0b | 1i |
| 0b | 0b | 0i |
| 0b | 1b | -1i |
| 0b | 0b | -1i |
| 0b | 1b | -2i |
| 0b | 1b | -3i |

As you can see, columns `on` and `off` are boolean and triggered based on values from other columns not shown, whereas `csum` tracks the cumulative sum of these two columns giving a value of `1` for each *on* value and `-1` for each *off* value.

Suppose I now wanted to update `on` and `off` such that the values change to `0b` if the corresponding `csum` value is `> 1i` or `< -1i` respectively.

That would be very easy to achieve using [Vector Conditional Evaluation](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/10_Execution_Control/#1013-vector-conditional-evaluation), with something like:

```
t:update on:?[on=1b and csum>1;0b;on], off:?[off=1b and csum<-1;0b;off] from t;
```

And this works as expected, however `csum` is not updating row by row to the changes made by the above query, instead the rows update to the below:

| on | off | csum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1b | 0b | 1i |
| 0b | 0b | 0i |
| 0b | 1b | -1i |
| 0b | 0b | -1i |
| 0b | 0b | -2i |
| 0b | 0b | -3i |

I know I can just run `csum` again and it will update but I would like a more efficient solution. I wouldn't mind a different approach to what I am doing here as long as I achieve the required end result.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's easier for others to help if you include some code to re-create your data set

Comment: Also, in the original data set, how does the 2nd row have a csum value of 0? As on and off are both 0, it should remain at 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, q's left-of-right syntax also means your conditional update to `on` and `off` is not doing what you expect. You should have parentheses around the comparisons to the `on` and `off` columns. However, you can drop the comparison in this case as the columns are already booleans, and no need for parentheses. (See my comment for the `csum` values in the original data set.)

```
q)t:update csum:sums on+neg off from ([]on:100000b;off:001011b)
q)update off:?[off=1b and csum>1;0b;on]from t
on off csum
-----------
1  0   1
0  0   1
0  0   0
0  0   0
0  0   -1
0  0   -2
q)update off:?[(off=1b)and csum>1;0b;on]from t
on off csum
-----------
1  1   1
0  0   1
0  0   0
0  0   0
0  0   -1
0  0   -2
q)update off:?[off and csum>1;0b;on]from t
on off csum
-----------
1  1   1
0  0   1
0  0   0
0  0   0
0  0   -1
0  0   -2
```

Aside from that, you will need to run the update statement again after you update the `on` and `off` columns. If this is something you need to do multiple times, consider iteration using https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#do:

```
q)f:{x:update on:?[on and csum>1;0b;on],off:?[off and csum<-1;0b;off]from x;update csum:sums on+neg off from x}
q)f t
on off csum
-----------
1  0   1
0  0   1
0  1   0
0  0   0
0  1   -1
0  0   -1
q)2 f/t       // f f t
on off csum
-----------
1  0   1
0  0   1
0  1   0
0  0   0
0  1   -1
0  0   -1
```

In this case the calculation reaches a fixed point after 1 iteration as the absolute values of all `csum` values are less than or equal to 1.

Comment: Some other things of note: kdb+ is flexible with column names in qsql statements e.,g.: `update ?[off and csum<-1;0b;off]from t`

Comment: How can I run that function iteratively so that I do not have to repeatedly run it (I have a very large dataset). I believe I am after `scan` but not sure what should be inside my square brackets.

Comment: My example gives you how to run it twice. This is the left argument of `2 f/t`. For more iterations, increase the left argument. If you want to run it until convergence (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#converge), use `f/[t]`

Comment: Perfect I see my mistake, was wanting it to converge but did not realise that square brackets were required for this. Thanks so much for your answer!